# Upstart - Django and Celeryd

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celeryd, celerybeat

I have my Ubuntu server setup so my Django project will bestarted by upstart like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
  set -e
  LOGFILE=/var/log/gunicorn/foo.log
  LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)
  NUM_WORKERS=3
  # user/group to run as
  USER=django
  GROUP=django
  cd /var/www/webapps/foo
  source ../env/bin/activate
  test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR
  exec ../env/bin/gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS \
    --user=$USER --group=$GROUP --log-level=debug \
    --log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE && celeryd -l info -B
```

As you can see I also added celeryd at the end. But its not started Im sure it does not start as my tasks is not getting done. When I start it in the terminal on the server with:

**manage.py celeryd -l info -B it does start and I can see the tasks being done.**

How am I supposed to start it with Django?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate upstart script for starting celeryd. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10251072/473232) should get you started.

Comment: hey please can anyone help me that i want to start the periodic task schedule at `10PM` today and this schedule of repeat at the interval of 60 seconds. then what should i do??