# Celery Daemon does not work on Centos 7

Tags: python, celery, daemon, centos7, systemd

I am trying to run celery daemon on Centos 7 which has systemd / systemctl.
It is not working.

- I tried a non-daemon case and it worked
- I ran ~mytask and that freezes up on the client machine and on the server where the celery daemon is running I get absolutely nothing logged.
- I have noticed that actually no celery processes are running.

Any suggestions as how to fix this?

Here is my daemon default configuration:

```
CELERYD_NODES="localhost.localdomain"
CELERY_BIN="/tmp/myapp/venv/bin/celery"
CELERY_APP="pipeline"
CELERYD_OPTS="--broker=amqp://192.168.168.111/"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/tmp/myapp"
CELERYD_USER="root"
```

Note: I am starting the daemon with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

and I got my celery daemon script from:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/celery/celery/3.1/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd

I also tried the one from:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/celery/celery/3.1/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd
but this one showed me an error when trying to start the daemon:

```
systemd[1]: Starting LSB: celery task worker daemon...
celeryd[19924]: basename: missing operand
celeryd[19924]: Try 'basename --help' for more information.
celeryd[19924]: Starting : /etc/rc.d/init.d/celeryd: line 193: multi: command not found
celeryd[19924]: [FAILED]
systemd[1]: celeryd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: celery task worker daemon.
systemd[1]: Unit celeryd.service entered failed state.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`celeryd` is depricated. If you are able to run in a non-daemon mode say

```
celery worker -l info -A my_app -n my_worker
```

You can simply daemonize it by using [celery multi](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.multi.html)

```
celery multi my_worker -A my_app -l info
```

That being said, if you still want to use `celeryd` [try these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14276580/2698552).

Comment: Great. I did not know this. Do you know why the document shows an example with "celery multi" followed by "celery worker" commands? I'm guessing that they are comparing and they are independent. Correct?

Comment: I tried it out. Celery multi would only work if you specify the pidfile and logfile.

Comment: yes, they are  showing celery multi equivalent of worker commands. there  is   no  need specify  pid, logfile; they are optional

Answer (score 6):

As @ChillarAnand has answered before, don't use `celeryd`.

But it is actually not as simple as he has written to run celery with `celery multi` with systemd.

Here are my working, non-obvious (I think) examples.

They have been tested on **Centos 7.1.1503** with **celery 3.1.23** (Cipater) running in a `virtualenv`, with the tasks.py example app from [Celery tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application).

#### Running a single worker

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=vagrant
Group=vagrant

# directory with tasks.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/vagrant/celery_example

# !!! using the below systemd is REQUIRED in this case!
# (you will still get a warning "PID file /var/run/celery/single.pid not readable (yet?) after start." from systemd but service will in fact be starting, stopping and restarting properly. I haven't found a way to get rid of this warning.)
PIDFile=/var/run/celery/single.pid

# !!! using --pidfile option here and below is REQUIRED in this case!
# !!! also: don't use "%n" in pidfile or logfile paths - you will get these files named after the systemd service instead of after the worker (?)
ExecStart=/home/vagrant/celery_example/venv/bin/celery multi start single-worker -A tasks --pidfile=/var/run/celery/single.pid --logfile=/var/log/celery/single.log "-c 4 -Q celery -l INFO"

ExecStop=/home/vagrant/celery_example/venv/bin/celery multi stopwait single-worker --pidfile=/var/run/celery/single.pid --logfile=/var/log/celery/single.log

ExecReload=/home/vagrant/celery_example/venv/bin/celery multi restart single-worker --pidfile=/var/run/celery/single.pid --logfile=/var/log/celery/single.log

# Creates /var/run/celery, if it doesn't exist
RuntimeDirectory=celery

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### Running multiple workers

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=vagrant
Group=vagrant

# directory with tasks.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/vagrant/celery_example

# !!! in this case DON'T set PIDFile or use --pidfile or --logfile below or it won't work!
ExecStart=/home/vagrant/celery_example/venv/bin/celery multi start 3 -A tasks "-c 4 -Q celery -l INFO"

ExecStop=/home/vagrant/celery_example/venv/bin/celery multi stopwait 3

ExecReload=/home/vagrant/celery_example/venv/bin/celery multi restart 3

# Creates /var/run/celery, if it doesn't exist
RuntimeDirectory=celery

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(Note that I am running workers with `-c / --concurrency` > 1 but it also works with it set to 1 or the default . Also this should work if you would not use `virtualenv`, but I strongly recommend you to use it.)

I don't really get why systemd can't guess the PID of the forked process in the first case and why putting pidfiles in specific place breaks the second case, so I have filed a ticket here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3459 . If I will get answers or come up with some explanations on my own, then I will post them here.

Comment: Use `%%n` instead of `%n`. Refer to https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3459 for further details.

Comment: You should add the line `RuntimeDirectory=celery` to make sure the /var/run/celery directory is created when the daemon is running.

Comment: Thanks @crey4fun , added that to my answer.

Comment: But I am not using `%n`, @Che-HsunLiu ...?